# Self Referencing Template

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
template< typename T >
class MyTemplate {
public:

    void myMethod( const MyTemplate< typename U > & )
    {
        return;
    };

};
```

where the myMethod argument `MyTemplate< typename U >` indicates the class instantiated with a different type.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you mean `const MyTemplate<U>&` ?

Comment: Wherever - example usage would be: `MyTemplate< int > a; MyTemplate< float > b; a.myMethod( b );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The syntax is as follows:

```
template< typename T >
class MyTemplate {
public:

    template< typename U >
    void myMethod( const MyTemplate<U> & )
    {
        return;
    };

};
```

This is a common construct. For some examples see [`std::shared_ptr`'s constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: Did you really mean to untemplatize the parent class?

Comment: @Andy: That was a copy-and-paste error which has been fixed. Thanks.